# I upload the CSS and Font File on the CDN Server (Amazon S3) and found these error. Please Suggest what can i do to solve it

Tags: amazon-s3

Access to Font at 'https://s3.cartwire.co/widget/cw/v2.0/css/font/opensans-regular.woff' from origin 'http://cwqa.srmtechsol.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

GET https://s3.cartwire.co/widget/cw/v2.0/css/font/opensans-regular.woff net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to add cors on s3 go through this link
[how to set cors on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html)